# Logistic regression from scratch in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, logistic-regression

Here is my logisticRegression class I developed to do gradient descent. There is this one line I marked as problematic

```
import numpy as np
class logisticRegression():
    """Logistic Regression classifier

    Parameters
    ----------
    alpha : float
        Learning rate(between 0.0 and 1.0).
    iters : int
        Number of iterations.

    Attributes
    ----------
    w_ : 1d-array
        Weights after fitting.
    """
    def __init__(self, alpha = 0.001, iters = 100000):
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.iters = iters

    def fit(self, X, y):
        """Fit training data
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : array-like, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
            Training vectors
        y : array-like, shape = [n_samples]
            Target values

        Returns
        -------
        self : object"""
        # Initialize weight
        self.w_ = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])

        self.errors_ = []
        m = X.shape[0]
        x0 = np.ones(X.shape[0])


        for _ in range(self.iters):
            h = self.hyp(X)
            gradient = (X.T)@(h - y)/m
            self.w_[1:] -= self.alpha*gradient
            self.w_[0] -= self.alpha*x0@(h - y)/m # This line is problematic !!!
        return self

    def sigmoid(self, z):
        """Compute sigmoid"""
        return 1/(1+ np.exp(-z))

    def hyp(self, X):
        """Compute hypothesis (probability)"""
        return self.sigmoid(self.w_[0] + X@self.w_[1:] )
```

I got wrong result. But if I rewrite this line as:

```
self.w_[0] -= x0@(h - y)/m # Remove the learning rate term
```

Then I got correct result. But this doesn't seem right. Did I oversee something here?

Comment: Please refer the mentioned link to learn and explore Logistic Regression. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-logistic-regression-in-python-step-by-step-becd4d56c9c8 https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/understanding-logistic-regression-python https://medium.com/@martinpella/logistic-regression-from-scratch-in-python-124c5636b8ac

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29137)

Answer (score 1):

For those who care, it turns out that removing the learning rate just makes the gradient happen faster. If alpha not removed, things still converge but incredibly slowly (it takes millions loops to converge)
My theory is that my math was right, but plain gradient descent is computationally expensive.